# How to mock input change for filtering data based on input string using react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

i have a component FilterInput that will take two props query and handle_input_change. this will filter the data based on value in input field.

i am writing unit test to check if it filters data based on the string entered in the input field using react testing library like below,

```
const data_mock = () => {
    return {
        data: [
            {"id":2,"description":"S", "start date": "2019-03-2"},
            {"id":1,"description":"something","start date":"2013-06- 
            14T00:00:00+00:00",}
       ],
   };
```

};

```
test('filters the description text', () => {
    const mock = data_mock();
   const handle_input_change = jest.fn();
   const {getByText} = render(
     <FilterInput query={""} on_handle_input_change={handle_input_change}> 
     </FilterInput>);
     const search_input_element = document.querySelector('.filter-input');
     fireEvent.change(search_input_element, {
         target: { value: 'something' },
     });
     const filtered_text = document.querySelector('.some > div:nth-of     - 
     type(1) > div:nth-of- 
     type(2)').textContent;
     const not_filtered_element = document.querySelector('.rdt_TableBody > 
     div:nth-of-type(2)');
     expect(not_filtered_element).toBeFalsy(); //this element should not be 
     //visible but is still present
 });
```

below is my code,

```
class App extends Component {
    const handle_input_change = (e) => {
         const query = e.target.value;
         this.setState(prevState => {
             const filtered_data = prevState.project_data.filter(element => 
             {
                 return 
             
            element.description.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) 
            || 
     
    element.project.toString().toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        });
        return {
            query,
            filtered_data
       }; 
   });
   return (
       <FilterInput query={this.state.input} on_handle_input_change= 
       {this.handle_input_change} />
   );
```

}

now the problem is when i run the test, the even though the query is provided in the input field, the data is not filtered.

i am not sure how to mock on_handle_input_change method for FilterInput component.

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about the formatting of your code? That `return` inside the `this.setState` only returns `undefined` since you have `element.description.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())` two lines after.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const {container} = render(
     <FilterInput query={""} on_handle_input_change={handle_input_change}> 
     </FilterInput>);
```

Instead of using the **document** directly, you can use **container**

```
 const search_input_element = container.querySelector('.filter-input');
 fireEvent.change(search_input_element, {
     target: { value: 'something' },
 });
```

Please try the above code.

Comment: thanks for some reason, when after inputing value something into the search_input_element it fails here expect(search_input_element.value).toEqual('something') i am not sure why it is not firing change event.